# My apache 2.4 reverse proxy is crashing after running for sometime

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, apache2.4

I have a reverse proxy configuration on windows and it is running on apache 2.4. There are some configuration settings are done in apache but after sometime it stops reporting few servers and throws an error:

> [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 5404:tid 23012] AH00326: Server ran out of threads to serve requests. Consider raising the ThreadsPerChild setting.

I also have enabled httpd-mpm.

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit              40
    StartServers             2
    MinSpareThreads          25
    MaxSpareThreads          75
    ThreadsPerChild          150
    MaxClients               1000
    MaxRequestsPerChild      0
    
    <IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers             3
    MinSpareThreads         75
    MaxSpareThreads        250
    ThreadsPerChild         25
    MaxRequestWorkers      400
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    ThreadStackSize      65536
    StartThreads           250
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads        250
    MaxThreads            1000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_mpmt_os2_module>
    StartServers             2
    MinSpareThreads          5
    MaxSpareThreads         10
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild       1000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 20000
    AcceptFilter http none
    AcceptFilter https none
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    MaxMemFree            2048
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    MaxMemFree             100
</IfModule>
```

Does anybody know any solution?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a crash but simply running out of threads. I'd begin by logging response time (%D), setting more aggressive timeouts, and adding some more capacity by boosting ThreadsPerChild.

9 times out of 10, the problem is a backend application hang.